# How to print the message using setTimeout function with the help of callback and promise concept?

Tags: javascript, callback, promise, settimeout

Below is the code snippet that I have written.My aim is to print the **message**.

```
delayedAlert(message:string, time: number, cb){
setTimeout(()=>{
    cb()
}, time)
};
```

//calling the function.

```
delayedAlert('Aditya', 3000, ()=>{
     console.log('done)
});
```

I want to print Aditya after 3secs, I am getting the console value, but this I don't want instead I want Aditya to be printed after 3 secs. And the same above **I have to write this code with Promise also.** Please ignore the typos.

Please Help.

Comment: The argument list of `delayedAlert` doesn't make sense.

Comment: what is this? typescript maybe??

Comment: You're not doing anything with the `message` parameter. Pass it to your callback.

Comment: Yes, this is in typescript.I want to print the message(which is the argument) after 3 secs, with using setTimeout function with the help of callback function.I have to use setTimeout internally in the function.

Comment: Um, you never print the message anywhere so why don't you try to `console.log(message)`

Comment: it says cannot find the message.

Comment: @Aditya and where do you stick that console.log line where it is not defined?

Comment: In the place where the function is called, in place of the previous console.log is written.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The promise won't need a call back, it will just act as a placeholder for a result of an asynchronous task.... 
In the example you can execute the function when the promise is resolved ..
(in the .then() funcion)

```js
function delayedAlert(message, time){
  return new Promise((resolve,reject)=>{
    setTimeout(()=>resolve(message), time);
  });
  
};


//calling the function.
//promise
let promise = delayedAlert('Aditya', 3000);

promise.then(message=>{
  console.log(message);
});

//callback
function delayedAlertCallback(message, time,cb){
    setTimeout(()=>cb(message), time);
};

delayedAlertCallback('Aditya2',4000,message=>console.log(message));
```

Comment: can you tell me without using callback and with Promise?

Comment: but I need Aditya to print after 3 seconds, that's the main point.It is printing done.same is happening with the code written in the question.we are calling the function

Comment: oh yes the answer is updated...you can pass arguments to the then function like any other function.

Comment: yes it works, thank you, but my first half of the answer is pending, where I have to use it with callback and without promise. will mark it complete as soon as that half part will be solved. thanks for solving the half part. :)

Comment: Note that you don't need the variable `a`, you can just return the promise directly.

Comment: Can you show the above example by using Observables and not with the callback, promises?It should take only 2 parameters message and time.@RenzoCC

Answer (score -1):

I put a basic js  (not typescript or any emacscript), and see your code got mistakes.
Look it as a [demo](https://fiddle.jshell.net/9jeg6m6n/) , you'll can the pass to typescript or any:

```
var delayedAlert = function(message, time, cb){
  setTimeout(function(){
      cb();
  }, time);
};
delayedAlert('Aditya', 3000, function(){
     console.log('done')
});
```